# Need to install Subversion 1.7.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: svn, ubuntu-16.04

I am having trouble finding the repository I need to point to in order to install an older version of Subversion on a recent release of Ubuntu. I need to install version 1.7.5 if possible.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to install Subversion 1.7.5. The version is outdated and is not supported. Moreover, it is even not the latest patch update in the 1.7.x release branch. The latest was 1.7.22.